# how to insert an excel sheet data to mongodb in nodejs via schema using mvc

Tags: node.js, excel, mongodb, model-view-controller, schema

how to insert an excel sheet data to mongodb in nodejs via schema using mvc
I hava an excel sheet with me with some data

I want to insert that data into mongodb
I have created schema for the same 
can I get a code for inserting the same to mongodb by using the mvc

Comment: Can you share your schema ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the sheet in CSV format and use [mongoimport](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/) to load it into your MongoDB database.

Comment: The mongoimport page I pointed you to has that exact example.

Comment: See https://developer.mongodb.com/quickstart/node-crud-tutorial for inserting content into MongoDB via Node.js